# How to find the remainder

Tags: polynomials

$f(x)$=$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$
What is the remainder when $f(x^{12})$ is divided by $f(x)$?

I think remainder theorem cannot be applied (at least directly) here.

I find that $f(-1^{12})$ - $f(-1)$ is $6$ but $f(1^{12})$ - $f(1)$ is $0$

Comment: It might help if you realise this is a geometric series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It is easier to calculate the remainder of $f(x^{12})(x-1)$ when divided by $f(x)(x-1)=x^6-1$, then divide that remainder by $x-1$ at the end.

Or more directly, note that:

$$x^6\equiv 1\pmod {f(x)}$$

so:

$$x^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{f(x)}$$

So what is $f(x^{12})\pmod{f(x)}$?

Comment: $f(x)(x-1)$ simplifies it. But $f(x^{12})(x−1)$ = $(x^{72}-1)(x-1)/(x^{12}-1) $does not help much.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't need to do that side. If $x^{6}\equiv 1\pmod{x^6-1}$ then $x^{12}\equiv ? \pmod {x^6-1}$. So $f(x^{12})\equiv ?  \pmod {x^6-1}$.

Comment: So it is 6. But is there any general rule to calculate  $f(x^{12})\pmod{f(x)} $once $x^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{f(x)}$ is known or it can only be done by observing the terms in the polynomial?

Comment: In general if $f$ and $g$ are polynomials and $a(x)\equiv b(x)\pmod {f(x)}$, then $g(a(x))\equiv g(b(x))\pmod{f(x)}$. In this case $g=f$ and $a(x)=x^{12}$ and $b(x)=1$. So $f(x^{12})\equiv f(1)\mod {f(x)}$

Comment: An alternative approach is to just note that the $f(x)$ has as roots the sixth roots of $1$, excepting $1$. And for each root, $r^{12}=1$ so $f(r{12})=f(1)$. So each root of $f(x)$ is a root of  $f(x^{12})-f(1)$, and, since $f(x)$ has not repeated roots, it must be a divisor of $f(x^{12})-f(1)$.